# Firebase Unity SDK 4.3.0 "java.lang.AbstractMethodError"

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I updated Firebase Unity SDK to version 4.3.0 and ran the Android Resolver. Now when the game launches it crashes after the scene begins to load with the error:

```
12-18 23:08:24.200  7493  7493 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.**.**, PID: 7493
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime: Unity version     : 2017.2.0p4
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime: Device model      : LeEco LEX720
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime: Device fingerprint: LeEco/ZL1_NA/le_zl1:6.0.1/WEXNAOP5802101261S/letv01261206:user/release-keys
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime: 
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$AuthStateListener.a(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)"
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.auth.k.run(Unknown Source)
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
12-18 23:08:24.202  7493  7493 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

PS: I also migrated from building on windows to building on mac so had to update android sdk

```
Android API            27  
Build Tools        27.0.2  
Platform Tools     27.0.0  
SDK Tools          26.1.1 
Play Services          46
```

Gradle file generated by unity in the Temp\GradleOut folder

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'GoogleAIDL', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GooglePlay', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'animated-vector-drawable-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'appcompat-v7-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'cardview-v7-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'common', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'customtabs-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'facebook-android-wrapper-7.10.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-impl-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-impl-license-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-analytics-license-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-app-unity-4.3.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-auth-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-auth-license-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-auth-unity-4.3.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-common-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-common-license-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-core-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-iid-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'firebase-iid-license-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-ads-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-ads-lite-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-base-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-base-license-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-basement-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-basement-license-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-gass-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-tasks-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-tasks-license-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-compat-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-core-ui-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-core-utils-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-fragment-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-media-compat-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-v4-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-vector-drawable-25.3.1', ext:'aar')
    compile project(':Firebase')
    compile project(':GoogleMobileAdsPlugin')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 27
        applicationId 'com.**.**'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb'
    }

    signingConfigs { release {
        storeFile file('/Users/home/Desktop/Unity Projects/UP - Android/user.keystore')
        storePassword '****'
        keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        keyPassword '****'
    } }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt','proguard-user.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt','proguard-user.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}
```

Proguard File:

```
-keep class com.facebook.** {*;}
-keep class com.unity.purchasing.** {*;}
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn com.google.vr.ndk.base.DaydreamApi

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.**{
public *;
}

# For old ads classes
-keep public class com.google.ads.**{
public *;
}

# For mediation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Other required classes for Google Play Services
# Read more at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
@com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-keep public class com.google.unity.**{
public *;
}
```

Unity 2017.2.0p4
MacOS High Sierra

**Note: It was working fine before I migrated to Mac and updated to Firebase UnitySDK 4.3.0**

Comment: what where u using before MAC?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same exception though I am on 4.4.0... It started happening after I added DynamicLink support.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by deleting the contents of the Library folder in Unity, re-importing all Firebase packages several times in various orders (I ended up with 4.4.1, but just updating from 4.4.0 to 4.4.1 did not do the trick on its own) and running a GooglePlay Resolver "force update" (I tried this too before updating Firebase, and after clearing Library folder, with no luck).

I can't say which of these things finally fixed it, but as noted, none of them worked in isolation, and no changes were made to any of my code or assets. It seems to be entirely a Firebase snafu.

It's interesting how Firebase packages overrides each other with non-identical files, so obviously 1) they are not independent and 2) the order in which you import them matters. I wish they would just create a single all-in-one asset and be done with it.

Comment: Of course, 4.4.1 does not work on iOS due to broken cocoa pods support. Thanks Google, just love wasting my life on this. (IOW: If you have this problem on Android and also need iOS support, DO NOT update to 4.4.1)